# Django channels consumer

Tags: python, django, django-channels

For django channels I have consumer file like this:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json


class chatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            'my_socket',
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()


    def receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            'my_socket',
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'data': text_data
            }
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        json_data = json.loads(event['data'])  # get received data as json
        respons_test = json.dumps(json_data)  # make response text
        print("chat_message") # Sometimes this is printed few times
        self.send(text_data=respons_test)
```

It seems `chat_message` method is running few times sometimes. I'm not sure how this exactly works but when I print into `chat_message`, it is printed sometimes once, sometimes more than once.  (I don't change clients/browsers count, and also in front-end, receiver gets message correctly, only one time).

Question: its normal few times running of `chat_message`? or I have something wrong in code?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'my_socket' 

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Use the above code.

Comment: Thanks, but I added `print` to `chat_message` method and it still prints few times

Answer (score 0):

It will print as many times as there are clients connected to the group `my_socket`. Every member of the group gets sent the message to the `chat_message` handler in their channel. Check your browser client or print in connect method to see how many clients connect to the group. It should print the same number of messages in the `chat_message` handler

Comment: I see. This is confusing though. A person might think it is a bug because it's the message repeated many times over depending on the connection number.

Comment: @dianesis not really it isn't. If you have a good understanding of how channels works then you will know it is supposed to work exactly that way. In the receive method, you see that he calls chat_message for a group. The message is sent through the channel layer to all the channels of the group members each of which have the method `chat_message`. So the function will run for every member of the group in separate channels (think class instances) and print as many times

Comment: Understood. Although I feel this is causing some issues in my current use case.

Comment: Right now I have a list which is populated with new players coming to the site. I do some operations with this list which is defined in settings to avoid any issues. For some reason consumer is not reading well from that list.

Comment: @dianesis I know it's been a while but it will probably be easier if you ask a separate question with details of your issue

Comment: I figure it out. The consumer will run per each connected user.. I found that the hard way.

Comment: Well, that was the whole point of this post. But I'm glad you figured it out:)